# Inserting Object Into Array Alphabetically From Nested Key Value

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

My app makes a http call and returns an array of objects. I need to loop over the objects and insert in to a new array in alphabetical order. Problem is the last item in the newly created array is the only item out of order.

Example code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zh16xc?file=package.json,index.ts

Aware i can use the native .sort(), however i am opting to forEach because i am performing more operations on each item, but the example has been trimmed down.

Code:

```
import { findIndex } from 'lodash';

let myList = [];

mockHttp()
  .then((res: Array<any>) => {
    console.log(res)
    res.forEach(item => {
      let index = findIndex(myList, function(listItem) { 
        return listItem.name.toLowerCase() > item.name.toLowerCase(); 
      });

      myList.splice(index, 0, {
        name: item.name,
        id: item.id,
        enabled: false
      })
    })

    console.log('result', myList);
  });

function mockHttp() {
   let p = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      resolve([
        {
          id: 'dscjidovvocsi', name: 'Pear'
        },
        {
          id: 'dscjidovvocsi', name: 'Banana'
        },
        {
          id: 'dscjidovvocsi', name: 'Orange'
        },
        {
          id: 'dscjidovvocsi', name: 'Blueberry'
        },
        {
          id: 'dscjidovvocsi', name: 'Grapefruit'
        },
        {
          id: 'dscjidovvocsi', name: 'Peach'
        },
        {
          id: 'dscjidovvocsi', name: 'Strawberry'
        },
        {
          id: 'dscjidovvocsi', name: 'Dragonfruit'
        },
        {
          id: 'dscjidovvocsi', name: 'Mango'
        },
        {
          id: 'dscjidovvocsi', name: 'Apples'
        }            
      ]);
   });

   return p;
 }
```

The last item is:
{
enabled: false,
id: "dscjidovvocsi",
name: "Pear"
}

Which is incorrect, all other items are ordered as expected.

Comment: even if you do more operations, you're not going to beat the built-in sort. `yourArray.map(whatever operation).sort()`.

Comment: `findIndex` returns `-1` if there is no matching element for the predicate, so when the `listItem` name is greater-than-or-equal to all existing names the new entry will be inserted at the beginning. Incidentally, you are definitely better off just sorting the array after all entries have been constructed – the asymptotic cost and optimised sort algorithm are better than anything you'll hand-roll with lodash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findIndex` will return `-1` if can't find a match.

When `-1` is passed as an index to `splice`, it inserts that in the second to last place, since negative indices count from the end, rather than the start.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3]
arr.splice(-1, 0, 4)
console.log(arr) // [1,2,4,3]
```

So you can fix it by detecting that case and making sure to insert it at the end instead with:

```
if (index === -1) index = myList.length
```

For example:

```
mockHttp()
      .then((res: Array<any>) => {
        console.log(res)
        res.forEach(item => {
          let index = findIndex(myList, function(listItem) { 
            return listItem.name.toLowerCase() > item.name.toLowerCase(); 
          });
          if (index === -1) index = myList.length // added

          myList.splice(index, 0, {
            name: item.name,
            id: item.id,
            enabled: false
          })
        })

        console.log('result', myList);
      });
```

---

FYI: I debugged this with this snippet in the loop:

```
console.log('inserting', item.name, 'at index', index, 'into', myList.map(v => v.name))
```

Which made it pretty clear what was going on when it logged this:

[image: debug results]